# How to only render part of an image in lwjgl/openGL

Tags: opengl, java, slick, masking

I'm making a mining/building game in java using slick2D and I want to make it so you can only see a few blocks in any direction while you are underground. The best example I could find of what I want to do is the game miner dig deep.

[image]

One way I thought of doing it would be to have a large image and just draw transparent areas on it where you need to be able too see but even if that would be an efficient method I wouldn't be sure how to do that.

Comment: Couldn't you just mask your buffer? Or have a texture with alpha overlayed on it?

Comment: if you want to mask in a rectangular area, consider using `glScissor`

Comment: It needs to be circular and I'm mainly using the slick libraries for rendering. I don;t know that much about openG but if someone could provide an example I would be able to implement it.

Comment: http://slick.ninjacave.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3598

Answer (score 2):

I'd just make an image with a transparent circle in the middle and the rest entirely black.  Then just render that over everything else in the game (except for the UI of course).